# Invalid version of dependency glib-2.0 when tring to meson build

Tags: ubuntu, glib, gnome

I was trying to build [GNOME todo](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-todo) app on Ubuntu 18.04.3 and when I use `meson build` I had the below error

```
Dependency glib-2.0 found: NO found 2.56.4 but need: '>= 2.58.0'
```

then I was upgrade the glib-2.0 through `sudo apt-get install glib-2.0` the console out was

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libspice-client-glib-2.0-dev' for regex 'glib-2.0'
Note, selecting 'libqt5glib-2.0-0' for regex 'glib-2.0'
Note, selecting 'gir1.2-spice-client-glib-2.0' for regex 'glib-2.0'
Note, selecting 'gir1.2-glib-2.0' for regex 'glib-2.0'
Note, selecting 'libspice-client-glib-2.0-1' for regex 'glib-2.0'
Note, selecting 'libspice-client-glib-2.0-8' for regex 'glib-2.0'
Note, selecting 'gir1.2-spiceclientglib-2.0' for regex 'glib-2.0'
gir1.2-glib-2.0 is already the newest version (1.56.1-1).
gir1.2-spiceclientglib-2.0 is already the newest version (0.34-1.1build1).
libqt5glib-2.0-0 is already the newest version (1.2.0-5).
libspice-client-glib-2.0-8 is already the newest version (0.34-1.1build1).
libspice-client-glib-2.0-dev is already the newest version (0.34-1.1build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

which I assume glib is already the newest version( but it's not ). Does anyone know how to upgrade glib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 will not have the newest version of GLib. They will stick with whatever is the newest version *in the same stable release series* as when 18.04 was released. From the looks of it, this would be GLib 2.56.x, not new enough for your purposes.

You have a few options:

- Build an older version of the app
- Upgrade to a newer Ubuntu version
- Download a GLib 2.58.x package from a newer Ubuntu version and any of its dependencies, and try to install it on your system (not recommended)
- Use a tool such as JHBuild to download newer versions of libraries and build them in a separate build environment
- Use a tool such as Flatpak to build the app in a pre-built environment with the right versions